# Solving the magical footer issue

Tags: css, stylesheet, position, footer

If you have a quick look at this website that I am designing: http://milabalami.com

The blackline seen in the footer is the one that I want to fix. Is there anyway that I can put that footer at the bottom of the content (wrapper) of the page? I have not done any webdesigning since the golden days of tables so CSS is quite new to me.

Anyone that could assist this old man? Please be specific in any reply as I am new to CSS styling...

Comment: maybe I'm missunderstanding your requirement but where `exactly` would you like the footer to go, because as far as I understand from your page's code it is repositioned by a piece of javascript. So what exactly are you after, and what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I want the footer to be at the bottom of the content. So depending on what the main body contains, the footer should be right underneath it. Think of it as HTML tables, that should make sense?

Answer (score 1):

you mean that you want to eliminate the gap between wrapper and the black line? If yes just change the `#blackbox2` margin to `margin: 0 auto 15px;`

Comment: I added that solution, if you have a look at this page: http://miladalami.com/?page_id=9 you will see that the black line is overlapping the left menu. Any solutions??

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
#blackbox2 {
background-color: black;
bottom: 0%;
height: 33px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 11%;
position: relative;
top: auto;
width: 900px;
z-index: 12;
}
```

Try removing `margin-top: 11%`.  This matches to '11% of the parent height', which is why your blackbox2 is so far from the wrapper above it.

Comment: the reason of why there is a 11% margin is because it was overlaping the menu

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem — http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ ?

Comment: No, that one brings the footer at the bottom of the screen. I want the footer at the bottom of the content.

Comment: So basically, depending on the height of the content, thats where the footer ends up. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's the default behavior. Check Sotiris' answer, maybe that solves it for you?